# How to check the change log of a Spacemacs layer's update

Tags: spacemacs

I update my Spacemacs layers very often.

How can we see the git log for those updates?

For example, the most recent `haskell-mode` layer has a bug, and I want to check it.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer:

[How to get release note of updated package in Spacemacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20021/how-to-get-release-note-of-updated-package-in-spacemacs)

Though it's not clear how to read the source code in each commit.